# How do I change the version of yarn used by my system?

Tags: macos, homebrew, yarnpkg

I am running Mac OS X 10.14.6 and I am trying to get the latest version of yarn installed and working on my system.

So I installed it with Homebrew, it tells me that I already have it installed on my system:

```
$ brew install yarn
Warning: yarn 1.21.1 is already installed and up-to-date
```

But when I do `yarn --version`, I get this:

```
$ yarn --version
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
```

So I try to reinstall it and the following happens:

```
To reinstall 1.21.1, run `brew reinstall yarn`
Transmit-Live $ yarn --version
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
Transmit-Live $ brew reinstall yarn
==> Reinstalling yarn 
==> Downloading https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.21.1/yarn-v1.21.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/784c559ca8d97--yarn-v1.21.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.21.1: 14 files, 5MB, built in 8 seconds
Transmit-Live $ yarn --version
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
```

I have also tried `brew switch` and that doesn't work:

```
$ brew switch yarn 1.21.1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.21.1
2 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.21.1
Transmit-Live $ yarn --version
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
```

**Edit 1**

I even tried to do `brew upgrade yarn` and it is the same issue:

```
$ brew upgrade yarn
Warning: yarn 1.21.1 already installed
Transmit-Live $ yarn --version
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.
Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
```

**Edit 2**

Output of `which yarn`:

```
$ which yarn
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@myapp/bin/yarn
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Basically what was happening is that I had two versions of `yarn` installed. One was a gem, and the other was the yarn executable.

So I simply ran `gem uninstall yarn` and it fixed it.

```
$ gem uninstall yarn
Remove executables:
    yarn
in addition to the gem? [Yn] Y
Removing yarn
Successfully uninstalled yarn-0.1.1
```

Now when I do `yarn --version` it works properly.

```
$ yarn --version
1.21.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade a package with `brew upgrade`, so something like

```
brew upgrade yarn
```

You may need to get homebrew to update it's package list first, with `brew update`

[Edit]

In your case there is some confusion, the `yarn` package that brew installs is the `javascript` package manager, whereas the `yarn` you have on your path is the ruby gem. You can upgrade the latter with `gem update yarn`. If you want to use the JavaScript package manager, try modifying your path, or use the fully qualified path (something like `/use/local/bin/yarn`)

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it still gives me the same issue. Check the updated question with those results.

Comment: What is the output of `which yarn`? Could be you have a locally installed variant...

Comment: Refresh the question for that output.

Comment: So that makes sense, but when I did `gem upgrade yarn` I get this: `While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)`

Comment: How would I modify the path or use the fully qualified path on OS X?

Comment: Temporarily, you could try typing `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. If this works, you will need to decide how you want to work with 2 distinct commands with the same name on your system. Or... If you just want to fix the ruby gem problem... Sorry, it should have been `gem update yarn`, not `upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I figured it out. See my answer that has what worked for me!

Comment: Thanks. Same to you :)